# Not able to close selenium webdriver object 4.11.0 and 4.12.1

Tags: java, windows, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, maven-3

Whenever am trying to close the webdriver its throwing the error as: "java.net.SocketException: Connection reset".
The code snippet, console logs and pom.xml is available on the following link: https://gist.github.com/SambathKumar/7a7c6c9659ae0fa4b3cadc0c7f61d76f

What is the issue and how to fix this issue?

**Orangehrm.java**

```
package sam.test;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class Orangehrm {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        ChromeOptions co=new ChromeOptions();
        WebDriver wd=new ChromeDriver(co);
        final int SLEEPSEC=3000;
        try {
            System.out.println("Before launch orange hrm");
            wd.get("https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/web/index.php/auth/login");
            System.out.println("After launch orange hrm");
            wd.manage().window().maximize();
            wd.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(SLEEPSEC));
            wd.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name='username']")).clear();
            System.out.println("After clearing the username field");
            wd.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name='username']")).sendKeys("Admin");
            System.out.println("After entering the username as Admin");
            wd.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name='password']")).clear();
            System.out.println("After clearing the password field");
            wd.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name='password']")).sendKeys("admin123");
            System.out.println("After entering the password as admin123");
            wd.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[type='submit']")).submit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            System.out.println("before close");
            //Thread.sleep(SLEEPSEC);
            wd.close();
            System.out.println("before quit");
            wd.quit();
            System.out.println("after quit");
        }

    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.sam</groupId>
  <artifactId>sam.test</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>test</name>
  
  <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.12.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
<!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.11.0</version>
        </dependency>-->

  </dependencies>


</project>
```

**console.logs**

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Oct 02, 2023 10:51:13 PM org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpVersionFinder findNearestMatch
WARNING: Unable to find an exact match for CDP version 117, so returning the closest version found: 116
Before launch orange hrm
After launch orange hrm
After clearing the username field
After entering the username as Admin
After clearing the password field
After entering the password as admin123
before close
Oct 02, 2023 10:51:16 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.WebSocket$Listener onError
WARNING: Connection reset
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.throwConnectionReset(SocketChannelImpl.java:394)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:426)
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBuf.setBytes(PooledByteBuf.java:254)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1132)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:151)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

before quit
after quit
```

Comment: Please paste the code here. People do not like to read text from link or image here.

Comment: @Tal Angel, I have uploaded code and console logs here.